# How to embed page navigation links on every page?

Tags: pdf, navigation

I need to put some of the items in Acrobat menu in the margin of every page of my document. I wonder if it can be done using, say, TikZ.

Comment: Hi, and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043). I removed the "Regards", which is just the style here. Any thanks should be expressed as the upvoting of answers that help you.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by *items in the menu*. Do you mean the button icons ? It's always good to have an image of the desired output. You don't have the reputation to post images here yet but upload the image and remove leading  `!` character from the link. Then we will add it for you.

Comment: Sorry I meant navigation menu.  I need to put a navigation menu for first page, next page, previous page, last page, print which appear on every page.

Comment: so like what occurs in a beamer presentation?

Comment: Yes Eric.  I can put the navigation menu as a running footer on every page using fancyhdr.  However I need the navigation menu to appear in the right margin of every page. I am happy to see the menu in two or more rows depending on the width of the margin.

Comment: I reopened the question because I understand what is asked and actually know a solution. @user12076: If this is for a specific class like `beamer` please state so.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a navigation panel using the `pdfscreen` package. The panel can also be customized as described in the package manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[screen,panelleft]{pdfscreen}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text for example
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```